# Wrong output Excel-VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWjdP.jpg)when i execute this function i get a wrong output which is 45 (count of the cells in whole the range) while the correct answer appears in the function dialog as you can see in the screenshot.
[image: Correct result is 15]

My code:

```
Function Countcolor(CountRange As Range, ColorRange As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim xBackColor As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Rng In CountRange
        qqq = Rng.Value
        xxx = Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
            xBackColor = xBackColor + 1
        End If
   Next

   Countcolor = xBackColor

  End Function
```

i was converting this tool into a function:

```
Sub DisplayFormatCount()
    'Updateby20150305
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim CountRange As Range
    Dim ColorRange As Range
    Dim xBackColor As Long
    Dim xFontColor As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId       = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set CountRange = Application.Selection
    Set CountRange = Application.InputBox("Count Range :", xTitleId, CountRange.Address, Type: = 8)
    Set ColorRange = Application.InputBox("Color Range(single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
    Set ColorRange = ColorRange.Range("A1")
    xReturn        = 0
    For Each Rng In CountRange
        qqq           = Rng.Value
        xxx           = Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
            xBackColor   = xBackColor + 1
        End If
        If Rng.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Font.Color Then
            xFontColor = xFontColor + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "BackColor is " & xBackColor & Chr(10) & "FontColor is " & xFontColor
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate your help.

Comment: I added code tags for you, but you haven't posted all the code. Plus I can't read your screenshot.

Comment: Hi SJR, this is all the code, i've uploaded another screenshot highlighting the result it shows 15 which is correct, but in the cell it writes 45 which is the count of all the cells.

Comment: what is qqq? what is xxx? why do you use `On Error Resume Next` ? Do you get an error if you delete that line?

Comment: yes i get error when i deleted On Error Resume Next #VALUE, but still in the dialog of Fx shows the correct result, regarding qqq and xxx i don't really know what are they actually i just was transforming a code into a function, i've wrote the original code in the post.

Comment: The error is happening on the IF line and thus the `xBackColor = xBackColor + 1` is always firing.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel  `.DisplayFormat` does not work when called as a function from the worksheet.

Comment: It should be noted, just changing the color may not change the count ,until the sheet recalculates.

Comment: Convert it from a function to a worksheet_calculate event that counts and puts the value in a cell.

Comment: @Davesexcel,any clue how to automate it?

Comment: Scott Craner, thanks for your support, but this doesn't work for conditional formatted cells.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question that mentions conditional formatting.

Comment: Could you use countif() to count how many "a"'s there are

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This works for me to count interior colors of a range

```
Function Countcolor(CountRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long

Dim Rng As Range
Dim xBackColor As Long
xBackColor = ColorRange.Interior.Color

For Each Rng In CountRange
    If Rng.Interior.Color = xBackColor Then Countcolor = Countcolor + 1
Next Rng

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for conditionally formatted cells.

Comment: As the OP's cells are conditionally formatted, this will not find matches.

Comment: My bad, I missed the conditional format part in Question

Comment: Foxfire, can you please share with me the code for conditional formatting?

Comment: Nope, I have no idea of how to deal with detecting colors applied by conditional formating.